# Bumper or Contact Plugin

Tags: ros, gazebo-sensor, contact

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hey everyone,

I am trying to implement some contact sensors for my robot model. I use the drcsim package as an orientation for available plugins.

I am wondering whether to use the gazebo_ros_bumper or the ContactModelPlugin plugin and what is the big difference between those two?

In my case "standard" information about collisions would work for me at the moment, like position of the collision and timing.

Thanks for your help

Christoph

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3173/bumper-or-contact-plugin/) by [Christoph](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/298/christoph/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 141 on 2013-06-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Today I downloaded the up to date gazebo_ros_pkgs from GitHub and build them as described in this [tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/Installing_gazebo_ros_Packages).

There only the bumper plugin is left, which more or less answers my question as I think.

I'll give that plugin a try.

---

Originally posted by [Christoph](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/298/christoph/) with karma: 141 on 2013-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0